# Define custom section command depending on placement in left or right column

Tags: sectioning, two-column, titlesec

I am trying to customize the `\section` command with the `titlesec` package so that the result will be different depending on whether the section header is in a left or right column.

Ideally I would like something that looks like the MWE below, but where the `leftsection` and `rightsection` commands are combined into one command that determines whether or not the current header is in the left or right column.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[english,a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Left section
\titleclass{\leftsection}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{leftsection}
\titleformat{\leftsection}{\Large\scshape}{\theleftsection \qquad #1}{0em}{~}
\titlespacing{\leftsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

% Right section
\titleclass{\rightsection}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{rightsection}
\titleformat{\rightsection}{\Large\scshape}{#1 \qquad \therightsection}{0em}{~}
\titlespacing{\rightsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\leftsection{Left Section}
\lipsum[5]
\newpage

\rightsection{Right Section}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image: Pedestrian attempt at creating different left and right section headers]

Comment: \if@firstcolumn for twocolumn (after \par).  Use the IndexColumns counter with multicol.

Comment: You could use the `paracol` package which provides synchronisation for left/right columns.

Comment: do you always force a page/column break (which makes it much easier) or do you want normal automatic breaking wuth the section heading switching depending on its final location 9which is harder and probably takes at least a couple of passes to collect information.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, that works thanks! If you make that an answer I will accept it. Best, T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `\leftsection` and `\rightsection` are doing what you want.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[english,a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Left section
\titleclass{\leftsection}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{leftsection}
\titleformat{\leftsection}{\Large\scshape}{\theleftsection \qquad #1}{0em}{~}
\titlespacing{\leftsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

% Right section
\titleclass{\rightsection}{straight}[\section]
\newcounter{rightsection}
\titleformat{\rightsection}{\Large\scshape}{#1 \qquad \therightsection}{0em}{~}
\titlespacing{\rightsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]% #1 = title
{\par\if@firstcolumn\leftsection{#1}%
 \else\rightsection{#1}%
 \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mysection{Left Section}
\lipsum[5]
\newpage

\mysection{Right Section}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\section` directly, although in edge cases the formatting *might* turn out to be wrong. For maximum safety, probably some `\needspace` instruction should be added at the beginning of `\section`.

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\formatsection}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\formatsectionnonumber}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\formatsection}[1]{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \thesection\qquad#1\filright
  \else
    \filleft #1\qquad\thesection
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\formatsectionnonumber}[1]{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    #1\filright
  \else
    \filleft #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\section*{Left Section}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Left Section}
\lipsum[2-4]

\section{Right Section}
\lipsum[5]

\section*{Right Section}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `needspace`:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox,needspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\formatsection}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\Large\scshape}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\formatsectionnonumber}

\preto\section{\needspace{5\baselineskip}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\formatsection}[1]{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    \thesection\qquad#1\filright
  \else
    \filleft #1\qquad\thesection
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\formatsectionnonumber}[1]{%
  \if@firstcolumn
    #1\filright
  \else
    \filleft #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\section*{Left Section}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Left Section}
\lipsum[2-4]

\section{Right Section}
\lipsum[5]

\section*{Right Section}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```